# Laravel Include Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Good day,

Here is my directory structure for blades.

```
resources/views/red/main.blade.php
resources/views/red/include_me.blade.php
resources/views/blue/main.blade.php
resources/views/blue/include_me.blade.php
```

This is the include in the red main.blade.php...

```
@include('red.include_me')
```

This is the include in the blue main.blade.php...

```
@include('blue.include_me')
```

Is there a way to include it so I no longer have to specify red or blue?

```
@include('include_me')
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, relative paths for Blade are not currently supported. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
@php $part = (condition) ?  'red' : 'blue'; @endphp
@include($part . '.include_me')
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope that is not possible. How should Laravel / Blade distinguish between them? `blue` and `red` act as a namespace here. You also can not have two files with same name in same folder.